# How to find out what is launching a port scan in the night from my Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, port-scanning

I have several Linux (mostly Debian) servers running on a Proxmox platform. All of them connecting to Internet through an ADSL line, with only one public IP.

One of them is running OMD (open monitoring distribution) since longer than a year ago to monitor an EXTERNAL server (other network, monitored through that ADSL connecting to Internet.

Now I have received a message from the owners of the remote server saying that they have detected a port scan run in the night from my ADSL public IP scanning their open ports.

It's the second time this happens to me with a Debian system :(

I need to detect the process running that scan

- how can I find out what process is launching that portscan from the offending linux box? The difficulty here is that I'd need to run -whatever- to know the process when the scan takes place -which can happen at some moment in the night-.
- Is there a way to get a list of processes that have somehow being launched and then finished between two times (i.e. new processes started from 23:00 to 03:00)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you place an IDS (Intrusion Detection System) on your network in order to identify the offending system. [Snort](https://www.snort.org/) is a widely used IDS that would be suitable for the job. It would probably be easiest to configure a span port on your router to send all outgoing traffic to the IDS. The Snort rules you can download from their website will generate alerts if port scanning occurs.

While the IDS is running you should simultaneously monitor processes on the Linux systems you suspect to be conducting the unwanted scanning. A simple script could be created to save process listings at a time interval, or list unique processes discovered with timestamps. If something more professional is desired, I'm sure there is some sort of freely available process logging software.

Run the IDS and process monitoring overnight. Find the unwanted port scanning in the IDS alerts to identify the system. Cross-reference the time of the alert with the process logging in order to track down what is creating this traffic.

Good luck.